# Write arraylist in XML file

Tags: android, xml, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I m trying to customize my list view to add image icons and text views. I have a array list stored need to convert it into XML file first. Please help me out to write this array list(contains file names stored on FTP server) into xml file stored in internal storage.

Comment: why do you need to convert it into XML? is it for caching purposes?

Comment: because i m unable to directly bind my array list to a custom list view, by converting writing it into xml file i can get arraylist<HashMap<String,String>>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write arraylist in xml file. just create one adapter class and hold the context with the arraylist in its constructor.

Then pass the arraylist data in your activity when you initialize the adapter class and add all data inside your custom xml views through getView().

**EDIT**

Your adapter class should be something like(Suppose your custom layout has 2 views i.e one textview and one checkbox):

```
 public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrayListData= null;
 private Context mContext;

 //Define your constructor in which you pass your arraylist data with usable activity context 
 public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrayListData) {
 this.mContext = mContext;
 this.mArrayListData= mArrayListData;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
   return data.length;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 private class MyViewHolder {
   TextView fillData;
   CheckBox statusCheck;

    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        statusCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkit);
        fillData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewFillData);
      }
   }

  //Do whatever you want to do with your custom layout here
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final MyViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourcustomlayout, null);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

          HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>();
    value = data.get(position);
          holder.fillData.setText(value.get("Your_HashMap_Key");
          holder.statusCheck.setText(value.get("Your_HashMap_Key");
    holder.statusCheck.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

            return view;
      }
  }
```

And In Your Activity initialize the youradapter class with appropreate context and your arraylist data and then use the adapter object as listadapter.Somethink like:

```
YourAdapter mAdapter = new YourAdapter(YourActivity.this, your_arraylist);
your_list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Note: I write this code roughly, so please avoid camel case errors if any.Thank You